# How to extract part of a string from a filename and sed it into that file

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep, regular-expression, string

I'm looking to automate a process whereby a part of the filename is what is used to replace a value inside the file itself.

Currently I use a manual process that looks like this:

get the *orgname* manually

```
$ grep -o orgname......... *2017-04* |uniq
...
uname=123456&**orgname=ABC5678**&userType=PERSISTENT&userLoginName=someusername&eventType=FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPT&timeOfOccurrence=2017-03-12%2016%3A49%3A36
```

Then replace *orgname* with new name

```
$ sed -i 's/ABC1234/5678/g' `*`5678`*` ; sed -i 's/DEF2345/6789/g' `*`6789`*`; sed -i etc...
```

The final result would look like this:

`uname=123456&orgname=**1234**&userType=PERSISTENT&userLoginName=someusername&eventType=FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPT&timeOfOccurrence=2017-03-12%2016%3A49%3A36`

The files are named like this:

```
rsa.collect.rsa-IB_L**1234**-2017-03-12.log.web1.decrypt
```

Whatever is after *orgname=* needs to change from ABC5678 to whatever comes after Lxxxx, only in files with the same xxxx in its filename.

I'm having a hard time getting my head around how to extract that number from the file name and using it in a `sed`.  There are hundreds of files (each with their own date) and 6 different number pairs to work with.  I'm hoping to write a bash script that does this all at once.

I was trying to use `grep -P` combined with putting that into some sort of variable and using `sed` but maybe there is a better/easier way?

Let me know if there are any additional questions.

Comment: what does mean *only in files with the same xxxx in its filename.* ? Should it make replacements on multiple files at once?

Comment: Yes multiple files.  There are several hundred files in the dir that need to be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the filename is in a variable, you can use a shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operator to extract part of it. Then substitute that into the `sed` command. Below I use the substring operator to get 4 characters starting from position 20.

```
for file in rsa.collect.rsa-IB_L*.log.web1.decrypt; do
    orgname=${file:20:4}
    sed -i "s/orgname=[^&]*/orgname=$orgname/" "$file"
done
```

Comment: I think I may have found (one possible) solution but yours looks much better than mine. (Can't seem to figure out how to format this...)

for l in `ls`;  
        do  
                FI="$(echo $l |cut -c21-24)"  
                ORG="$(grep -o orgname........ $l | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d"&" -f1|uniq)"  
                sed -i 's/$ORG/$FI/g' $l|grep $FI  
done

Comment: Thank you for much for this, so much more elegant than my own solution!